# laravel groupBy() and count() in addSelect

Tags: laravel

I try build a query but something is wrong, because it return the items number within first group, not the groups count.
What is the correct way?
(Laravel 6.x)

```
$query->addSelect(['tire_set_count' =>
            DeliveryNoteItem::select(DB::raw('count(*)'))
                ->whereColumn('delivery_note_items.delivery_note_id', 'delivery_notes.id')
                ->groupBy('car_id'),
        ]);
```

Comment: you should select car_id when you groupBy('car_id')

Comment: I have try, but it does not work

**DeliveryNoteItem::select(DB::raw('car_id, count(*)'))**

Comment: i think DeliveryNoteItem::select(DB::raw('count(*)'),'car_id')

Comment: Result: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

Comment: I think the problem is addSelect. The groupyBy and count works different within.

Comment: what do you want, can you put it in the sample `sql query` then we can figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved :)

```
$query->addSelect(['tire_set_count' =>
            DeliveryNoteItem::selectRaw('count(distinct car_id)')
                ->whereColumn('delivery_note_items.delivery_note_id', 'delivery_notes.id'),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query, it will solve your problem:

```
$query->addSelect(['tire_set_count' =>
    DeliveryNoteItem::selectRaw('count(*) AS result')
        ->whereColumn('delivery_note_items.delivery_note_id', '=', 'delivery_notes.id')
        ->groupBy('car_id'),
]);
```